# Need help understanding the format ".2f" command and why it is not working in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing on my format statements, but i'm not quite understanding how it works. I am specifically trying to understand the format command using the ".2f" command this is the code i currently have, the second line runs before it returns and error:

```
salesTax = 0.08

salesAmount = str(input('Enter the sales amount: '))

print ('The sales amount is', format('$'+salesAmount, 
'.2f'))

print ('The sales tax is', format("$"+'.2f'))

print('The total sale is', format("$"+totalSales*salesTax, 
'.2f'))

input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

I am trying to make a script, that displays the output of the following sample run:

```
//Sample run:
Enter the sales amount: 1234
The sales amount is $ 1,234.00
The sales tax is $ 98.72
The total sale is $ 1,332.72
Run complete. Press the Enter key to exit
```

Comment: The syntax is `"formatString".format(value1, value2, value3, ...)`

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Comment: Hmm, there's also a function `format`: `format(value, format_string)`, but it's not commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

```
print('The sales amount is $', format(salesAmount, '.2f'))
```

Breaking it down:

Convert the number to string formatted as 2 decimal places (`.2` portion) with floating point representation (`f` portion).

```
format(salesAmount, '.2f')
```

Now that you have a string, you join it with either pass to print or you could join to previous code with `+` or whatever.

```
'The sales amount is $' + the_formatted_number
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful, I know its an easy concept, but I just couldn't rap my head around it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

.2f should be outside of the format method.
eg try `print("{:.2f}".format(12.345678))`

Comment: That is not correct. He is not using the format method but the format function which expects 2 arguments and is meant for a single element

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
format(value, format_spec)
```

When you use a `.2f` format, the value should be a `float`, not a string, so you need to convert the input to `float` (`input()` returns a string, there's no need to use `str()` on the result. And you can't concatenate `$` to the value before formatting it, you need to concatenate that to the result.

You also used a nonexistent variable `totalSales` in your `print()` calls, it should be `salesAmount`.

```
salesTax = 0.08
salesAmount = float(input('Enter the sales amount: '))
print ('The sales amount is', '$' + format(salesAmount, '.2f'))
print ('The sales tax is', '$' + format(salesTax*salesAmount, '.2f'))
print('The total sale is', '$' + format(salesAmount + salesAmount*salesTax, '.2f'))
input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

That said, this use of the `format()` function is not common these days. It's easier to use an f-string or `str.format()`, which allows you to embed the format spec in a string with the plain text, and format multiple values together, e.g.

```
print("The sales amount is ${.2f}".format(salesAmount))
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the amazing and detail response, I will keep that in mind and will probably write a new script practicing with the str.format() now as well.

Answer (score 1):

[`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) is a built-in function that takes two arguments: `value` and `format_spec`.

### `format('$' + salesAmount, '.2f')`

Will give you an error because it is expecting a number or a string representation of a number as `value` to apply the format you have provided. You will get an error:

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

### `format(salesAmount, '.2f')`

This will work properly.

**Note:** If you are using Python 3.6+ you can also use an f-string:

```
f"{12.345678:.2f}"
```

Comment: Although this works, you're not explaining how the format *function* works, which is what was requested

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf thank you for you clarification ill keep that in mind when using the format command.